# Why getViewTypeCount() return different values?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have only one layout which inflated. After add new item to listview I catch this exeption as below, it happen when I trying scrolling to up. If getViewTypeCount() will return 1, I will have a big [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734151/listview-correctly-display-only-10-items)

```
D/countOfType﹕ getViewTypeCount() = 8
D/countOfType﹕ getViewTypeCount() = 7

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
        at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:6563)
```

Here is code of my adapter

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final Tracker tracker = trackerList.get(position);
    final Thread thread = tracker.getThread();
    ViewHolder holder;
    long days,hours,minutes,seconds;
    long eDays,eHours,eMins,eSecs;

    if(row == null){
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    //изнальначальный вид
    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    finalHolder.name.setText(tracker.getName());
    Log.d("TrackAdapter","getView() = "+position);
    if(tracker.getElapsedTime()!=0 && tracker.getLimitTime()==0){//если прошедшее время !=0 и таймер без лимита
        days = tracker.getElapsedTime()/86400000;
        hours = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/3600000)%24;
        minutes = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/60000)%60;
        seconds = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/1000)%60;
        if(days!=0)
            finalHolder.days.setText(Util.concat(days <= 9 ? 0 : "", days));
        if(hours!=0)
            finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours <=9 ?0:"",hours));
        if(minutes!=0)
            finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));
        if(seconds!=0)
            finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(seconds<=9?0:"",seconds));
    }else{
        if(tracker.getIsFinished()){//если таск закончен, дошел до лимита
            hours = (tracker.getLimitTime()/3600000)%24;
            minutes = (tracker.getLimitTime()/60000)%60;
            seconds = (tracker.getLimitTime()/1000)%60;
            finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            finalHolder.textFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(seconds!=60)
                finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(seconds<=9?0:"",seconds));
            if(minutes!=60)
                finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));
            if(hours!=24)
                finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours <= 9 ? 0 : "", hours));

        }else{
            if(tracker.getLimitTime()!=0){//если установлен лимит, но еще не дошел до конца
                days = tracker.getLimitTime()/86400000;
                hours = (tracker.getLimitTime()/3600000)%24;
                minutes = (tracker.getLimitTime()/60000)%60;
                finalHolder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                finalHolder.limHours.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                finalHolder.limDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                finalHolder.limMin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                finalHolder.limDay.setText(Util.concat(days <= 9 ? 0 : "", days, ":"));
                finalHolder.limHours.setText(Util.concat(hours <= 9 ? 0 : "", hours, ":"));
                finalHolder.limMin.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",minutes));

                eDays = (tracker.getElapsedTime() / 86400000);
                eHours = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/3600000)%24;
                eMins = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/60000)%60;
                eSecs = (tracker.getElapsedTime()/1000)%60;

                if(eSecs!=0)
                    finalHolder.seconds.setText(Util.concat(eSecs<=9?0:"",eSecs));
                if(eMins!=0)
                    finalHolder.minutes.setText(Util.concat(minutes<=9?0:"",eMins));
                if(eHours!=0)
                    finalHolder.hours.setText(Util.concat(hours<= 9 ? 0 : "", eHours));
                if(eSecs!=0)
                    finalHolder.days.setText(Util.concat(days<= 9 ? 0 : "", eDays));


            }else {
                finalHolder.textLimit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finalHolder.limHours.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finalHolder.limDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finalHolder.limMin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
    if(tracker.getIsStart() && !tracker.getIsFinished()) {//если был стартован
        finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    tracker.setHolder(finalHolder);
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btStart:
                    tracker.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    tracker.setIsStart(true);
                    tracker.setHolder(finalHolder);
                    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if(tracker.getUpdateTime()==0)
                        thread.start();
                    else
                        tracker.getThread().start();

                    break;
                case R.id.btStop:
                    tracker.setLastPause(tracker.getUpdateTime());
                    finalHolder.stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tracker.setIsStart(false);
                    break;

            }
        }
    };
    finalHolder.start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    finalHolder.stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    return row;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    Log.d("countOfType","getViewTypeCount() = "+getCount());
   if(getCount()==0)
      return super.getViewTypeCount();
    else
      return getCount();
    //return 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}


static class ViewHolder{
  @InjectView(R.id.tvName) TextView name;
  @InjectView(R.id.tvDays) TextView  days;
  @InjectView(R.id.tvHours) TextView  hours;
  @InjectView(R.id.tvMinutes) TextView minutes;
  @InjectView(R.id.tvSeconds) TextView  seconds;
  @InjectView(R.id.btStart) ButtonFloatSmall start;
  @InjectView(R.id.btStop) ButtonFloatSmall stop;
  @InjectView(R.id.txtFinish) TextView  textFinish;
  @InjectView(R.id.txtLimit) TextView textLimit;
  @InjectView(R.id.limDay) TextView limDay;
  @InjectView(R.id.limHours) TextView limHours;
  @InjectView(R.id.limMin) TextView limMin;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        ButterKnife.inject(this,view);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Why getViewTypeCount() return different values?" -- because you wrote it to return different values. If you want it to have a fixed value, return a fixed value, not `getCount()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare
You are right, but if I will return 1 as should, my items will mixed with scrolling

Comment: "my items will mixed with scrolling" -- that would indicate bugs in your `getView()` implementation. Fix the bugs.

Comment: @CommonsWare
in getViewTypeCount() I wrote return getCount() +1;
it solves problem with catching exeption. it's looks like a big crutch, but worked for me. Another problem, after removing items and adding new, they inserted with new names but in old views

Comment: "Another problem, after removing items and adding new, they inserted with new names but in old views" -- that would indicate bugs in your `getView()` implementation. Fix those bugs, then get rid of the cache-busting `getViewTypeCount()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** As a general rule, for every `if` you have in your `getView(...)`, make sure there is an `else` that handles the negative case or you will see old data in your views.

---

It seems you are misunderstanding the role `getItemViewType(int position)` and `getViewTypeCount()` play.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5301093/868492) is a good description of why and how to use them.

In your case, since you only have one layout, implementing either method should not be necessary.  If you are seeing recycled data in your views, then there is some bug in your `getView(...)` method.  Make sure you handle all cases when populating a view with data.

For example, say you have a list of items and you want to display a red background if the position is even and blue if it is odd.  Lets also assume that by default your view has a red background.  You might implement your `getView(...)` like so:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        //Inflate your view here
    }
    if(position % 2 != 1) {
        //Only need to change background if we're odd, since it's red by default
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
}
```

At first glance, this seems like a good implementation.  When you add in view recycling, however, you will see that some of your even views may end up with a blue background.  The reason for this is because you don't explicitly set the background for even views so they will remain the color they were set to in the previous row they were used in.  A better implementation would be:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        //Inflate your view here
    }
    if(position % 2 != 1) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else {
        //Set the background no matter what so we make sure our view reflects our data
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```